# Different texture for multiple resolution

Tags: libgdx

How to use different texture(image) for different resolution in libGDX? Also specify how to detect it from asset folder?

Comment: You really need to expand this question and tell us what your problems are and what research you've done so far yourself. How are we supposed to help you reading just this single line blurp of thoughts :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is pretty vague, but if I'm interpreting it correctly, you're going to need to do it manually, but libgdx can help. You're going to want to use the [`ResolutionFileResolver`](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/source/browse/trunk/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/assets/loaders/resolvers/ResolutionFileResolver.java). The author of libgdx provides an example in his [`AssetManagerTest`](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/source/browse/trunk/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/AssetManagerTest.java). I wrote about how to use the `ResolutionFileResolver` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9607334/324625).

I think if you read through the code, that should be enough to get you started, and you can come back with more specific questions.